# Pandas - Select month and year

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Trying to subset a dataframe, ultimately want to export a certain month and year (Say November 2020) to a CSV. But I'm stuck at the selection part, the date column is in DD/MM/YYYY format. My attempt -

```
csv = r"C:\Documents\Transactions.csv"
current_month = 11
current_year = 2020
            
data =pd.read_csv(csv, sep=',', index_col = None)
        
df = data[pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],dayfirst=True).dt.month == current_month &(pd.to_datetime(data['Date']).dt.year==current_year)]
            
print(df)
```

Result is the rows with the correct year, but includes all months whereas I want it restricted the current_month variable. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a Date column, I would suggest to first convert the column as you do it twice. You cannot apply .dt.month to the Series (whole column).
Then just apply it to the Series.

```
import datetime as dt
data['Date']= pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df = data[(data['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.month) == current_month) & 
(data['Date'].apply(lambda y: y.year) == current_year)]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766353/pandas-to-datetime-parsing-wrong-year

Answer (score 1):

Convert column `Date` to date format first, then do the selection part as usual.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data-date.txt')
current_month = 11
current_year = 2020
    
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df[(df['Date'].dt.month == current_month) & (df['Date'].dt.year == current_year)]
```