# Using timedelta and strftime on column converted to datetime

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

**GOAL:** After reading a *.csv to a dataframe, I want to convert a column of birth dates to this format: `%m-%d-%Y`. And then write them to excel. The *.csv has 600K+ records.

**Summary**: I have dates for both the 20th and 21st centuries, and the years sometime overlap. For example, I can have four-digit years from 1901 and 2001. Because of this, I had to use a code snippet borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766353/pandas-to-datetime-parsing-wrong-year#answer-47243438).

**What I've tried and what I expected:**
I originally converted the column to datetime, and used `strftime('%m-%d-%Y')`. But, then the year 1970 and before would be written as 20--. For example, the years 2070 and 2068 here should be 1970 and 1968, respectively. And the birthdate column is `dtype` `object`, if it matters.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

#birthdate column
birthdate = 'PATIENT_BIRTH_DATE'
#after reading the *.csv to a dataframe, convert the birthdate column to %m-%d-%Y format
df[birthdate] = pd.to_datetime(df[birthdate]).dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")

#prints
0    08-24-1996
1    10-16-1971
2    02-19-2070
3    09-25-2068
```

So, then I used the above-mentioned code snippet to fix that. However, now I can't seem to remove the time from the date that gets written to Excel. If I print to the terminal I don't get the time, but when I write to Excel I do. It looks like this: `1996-08-24 00:00:00`

```py
df[birthdate] = pd.to_datetime(df[birthdate])

future = df[birthdate] > datetime.today()
df.loc[future, birthdate] -= timedelta(days=365.25*100)
```

If I use `df[birthdate] = pd.to_datetime(df[birthdate]).dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")` here, I get an error: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'`

Comment: To clarify: basically your issue is that you have 2-digit years in your data source (csv)?

Comment: @MrFuppes It's confusing. The formula bar in the *.csv shows 6/7/1943, for example. But the field value shows 7-Jun-43. So, I don't know how to answer your question exactly.

Comment: but you have data in csv format? or is it an xls(x) file? - if it's a csv, you can open it in a text editor (e.g. [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is nice on Windows) and check the "real" format, not what Excel tells you. Excel likes to think for you, which is not always clever ^^

Comment: Yes, the source file is *.csv format. I opened it in notepad++ and the date is shown as 7-Jun-43. What are you getting at exactly?

Comment: That wasn't meant to come out as snippy. I'm just curious where you're going with the 2-digit years.

Comment: no worries, just wanted to make sure I got the question correctly. I've added a minor suggestion as an answer since I found it to be too long for a comment ;-) I think @JoeThor 's answer has what you need to *write* the output for Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is formatting it, but you can update that selection while writing to the workbook.

You can use the the xlsxwriter engine to specify the format of a given column.

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html

Here is a guide on formatting dates with xlsxwriter as well, but I provided a solution from what I could infer below

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html?highlight=date%20format

This will only work if the column is in datetime format, so it may be necessary to validate that using this snippet

```
df['date1'] = df['date1'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Then run the following, being aware of the column where the formatting is applied will change based on which column in the dataframe has the datetimes.

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
# %m-%d-%Y
format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm-dd-yyyy'})

# Set the column width and format.
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format)

writer.save()
```

Comment: I converted the column to datetime using: ```df[birthdate] = pd.to_datetime(df[birthdate], errors='coerce')```. Then I used your ```df['date1'] = df['date1'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')```. But, I still can't get past the ```TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'```, which is referring to this line: ```df.loc[df[birthdate] > pd.Timestamp('now'), birthdate] -= pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)```.

Comment: So it sounds like the `df.loc[df[birthdate] > pd.Timestamp('now'), birthdate] -= pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)` is causing the error. I would do the conversion of `df['date1'] = df['date1'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')` after you do the offsetting process.

Answer (score 1):

A minor addition, to account for the 100 years offset, I'd suggest

```
import pandas as pd

birthdate = 'PATIENT_BIRTH_DATE'
df = pd.DataFrame({birthdate: pd.to_datetime(["08-24-1996", "10-16-1971", "02-19-2070", "09-25-2068"])})

df.loc[df[birthdate] > pd.Timestamp('now'), birthdate] -= pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)

df
  PATIENT_BIRTH_DATE
0         1996-08-24
1         1971-10-16
2         1970-02-19
3         1968-09-25
```

instead of using average number of days per year.

---

+1 for the ***"never-use-two-digit-years"*** bucket.