# Why does pandas interpret Aug-30 as 1930-08, but not 2030-08?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a series of dates, from Aug 1990 to Aug 2040. Its format is "Aug-00" for Aug 2000. I read in the data using pd.read_excel. Pandas interpret "Aug-30" onwards as "Aug 1930", and so on. How to let pandas know it's 2030, but not 1930.

Comment: What happens if you change the formatting of the cells in the excel file before passing the file to `pd.read_excel`?

Comment: Why? Well, someone has to choose. If you see a date like 3/7/17, how do you know it's 1517, 1617, 1917 or 2017?

Comment: I would have expected it to parse `Aug-30` as the 30th of August. Can you show your code?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: There's a very different cutoff in that question.

Comment: when I tried `pd.to_datetime("Aug-30", format="%b-%y")` the result -> `Timestamp('2030-08-01 00:00:00')` please show your code

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: maybe, because of Excel. But the solution is the same, especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/47243438/480982

Comment: Thanks for all your comment. It's a good point to reformatting the cell. I downloaded the data from somewhere. Seems the excel recognize Aug-30 as 1930-01-01. Not sure if it's due to some conversion issue when downloading the data. My code is simply pd.read_excel(file). Nothing more than that.