# How to convert number to date of birth based on important circumstances in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
number
----------
54062903812
96120309725
00021201044
00346
```

I need to create new column where I need to convert first 6 elements of each value from column "number" to birthday date:
For example:

- values 1 and 2 means year of born
- values 3 and 4 month of born
- values 5 adn 6 day of born

  - 54062903812 = 1954-06-29
  - 96120309725 = 1996-12-03
  - 00021201044 = 2000-02-12

Currently I use below function to do it, but this function has a huge problem, because it return that 54062903812 is 2054-06-29 but it of course shoudl be 1954-06-29 and of course it is impossible. My code:

```
df["birthday"] = pd.to_datetime(df["number"].str[:6], format='%y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```

How can I modify my code so as to be able to recognize that:

- if it starts from <0 it is 1900
- if it starts from >=0 it is 2000

** Be aware that I need to convert only these values from column "number" which has 11 elements!!

Comment: The main problem comes from the data, for example if you have `21021201044` how do you know if this is 2021-02-12 or 1921-02-12 ?

Comment: good question, but this is as list of clients, so we can assume, that if first two numbeers == 99 or <99  or > 10 it is 1900 and if it is ==00 or >00 it is 2000.... So using your example 21.... 21 > 10 so it is 1900 -> 1921

Comment: well, in that case you could use a threshold, if the value is between 00 and 21 then it is 20** else it is 19***

Comment: Netim, coudl you present some example code ? and be aware taht we want to take this operation only for these numbers which have 11 elements :)

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766353/pandas-to-datetime-parsing-wrong-year

Comment: I need sample of code, not a link :)

Comment: Well.... `df['birthday'] = pd.Series([ f"19{y[:2]}-{y[2:4]}-{y[4:6]}" if int(y[:2]) > 21 else f"20{y[:2]}-{y[2:4]}-{y[4:6]}" for y in df['number']])` but the purpose of the link given by @tayfunyiğit is to show you that there is no good solution to your problem... Just modify the threshold to fit your needs

Comment: `df['birthday'] = pd.Series([f"19{y[:2]}-{y[2:4]}-{y[4:6]}" if int(y[:2]) > 21 else f"20{y[:2]}-{y[2:4]}-{y[4:6]}" if len(y) == 11 else 0 for y in df['number']]) ` to handle you len 11 problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you can assume from your data that any 00 to 21 is 2000 to 2021 you could try the code below.  It's one idea.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': {0: 54062903812, 1: 96120309725, 2: 21201044}})

def addYear(x):
    years = ['00' , '01' , '02' , '03' , '04' , '05' , '06' , '07' , '08' , '09' , '10' , '11' , '12' , '13' , '14' , '15' , '16' , '17' , '18' , '19' , '20' , '21' , '22']
    x = str(x)
    if x[:2] in years:
        x = '20' + x
    else:
        x = '19' + x
    x = pd.to_datetime(x[:7], format='%Y%m%d')
    return x

df['Date1'] = df.apply(lambda x: addYear(x['number']), axis=1)

print(df)


   number         Date1
0  54062903812  1954-06-02
1  96120309725  1996-01-20
2  21201044     2021-02-01
```

---

**Update:**

From the comments if len(x) < 11:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': {0: 54062903812, 1: 96120309725, 2: 21201044, 3: 1234}})

def addYear(x):
    years = ['00' , '01' , '02' , '03' , '04' , '05' , '06' , '07' , '08' , '09' , '10' , '11' , '12' , '13' , '14' , '15' , '16' , '17' , '18' , '19' , '20' , '21' , '22']
    x = str(x)
    if len(x) < 11:
        return 0
    else:
        if x[:2] in years:
            x = '20' + x
        else:
            x = '19' + x
        x = pd.to_datetime(x[:7], format='%Y%m%d')
        return x

df['Date1'] = df.apply(lambda x: addYear(x['Col1']), axis=1)

print(df)


          Col1                Date1
0  54062903812  1954-06-02 00:00:00
1  96120309725  1996-01-20 00:00:00
2     21201044                    0
3         1234                    0
```

Comment: don't need to define a list with valid year, you could just do `if int([:2]) <= 21`

Comment: The code above won't win any prizes.  It's not fancy or smart.  I just wanted it to be clear to the OP when looking at `00` and maybe adjust what's in the list.

Comment: I totaly agree with you that's what we discussed below the OP post in comment. The main problem with this question is that you don't have an universal solution and a choice has to be made for ambiguous date as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37766686/15320403

Comment: MDR it works, but how can we add also conditions that if value in column "number" has les that 11 element return for example 0 instead of date ?

Comment: Who knows what's in the whole dataset.  For example Herman Melville and Queen Victoria are both born in 1819.  If those birthdays are in the set then they all move to 2019.  :o)

Comment: Maybe `if len(str(x) < 11: return 0 else:` ...run the code in the function.

Comment: MDR in which part of function should I add: if len(str(x) < 11: return 0 else: ? could you modify your answer with this line ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df["birthday"] = pd.to_datetime(df.number.str[:6],format="%y%m%d", errors="coerce")   
df["birthday"] = df.birthday.apply(lambda x:x.replace(year=x.year-100) if x.year>2000 else x)
```

Comment: I typed 2000 as year but it depends on years you wanna change. For example You wanna keep 21 as 2021 instead 1921 then pass x.year >2021

Answer (score 0):

```
df['birthday'] = pd.Series([f"19{y[:2]}-{y[2:4]}-{y[4:6]}" if int(y[:2]) > 21 else f"20{y[:2]}-{y[2:4]}-{y[4:6]}" if len(y) == 11 else "0" for y in df['number']])
```