# Year changes when formatting

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to Python. Please guide, thank you.

I have a list of different date formats which I need to standardise them.

I am currently using `df['Birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birthday'], format = '%m/%d/%y')`

It works, but:

1. Formatted date is YYYY-MM-DD. I want MM/DD/YYYY.
2. 10/15/84 -> 1985-10-15, which is correct. But 10/27/70 -> 2070-10-27, I want 1970.

(1st pic: Raw; 2nd pic: Produced result; 3rd pic: Expecting)

[image: Raw data]
[image: Produced result]
[image: Expecting]

Comment: Note that `YYYY-MM-DD` is a _much_ better form to standardize on. It sorts cleanly (you can sort it as text and the values come out the same as if you'd sorted them as a date), and it isn't contingent on locale (since different parts of the world use `MM/DD/YYYY` and `DD/MM/YYYY` those two are by nature ambiguous).

Comment: Typo in `10/15/84 -> 1985-10-15`?

Comment: Anyhow -- can you provide a [mre] with code we can copy-and-paste to run ourselves to see the problem? Much better (for investigating solutions and being able to check that we understand the issue correctly) to produce something on our own system than to just be looking at screenshots. (Also, we don't know what application you made the screenshots in, and whether that application did its own reformatting!)

Comment: For the ambiguous 2-digit YY problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766353/pandas-to-datetime-parsing-wrong-year

Comment: @jarmod, hey thanks. that stackoverflow helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with the help of another stackoverflow and the comment

```
#To clean the BirthYear column
df['BirthYear'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BirthYear'])
df['BirthYear'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BirthYear'], format = '%m/%d/%y')

#For when xx50 is the cut off and anything above becomes 20xx
#(for eg: 1970 -> 2070)

i = 0

while i < 250:
    if df['BirthYear'][i].year > 2050:
        df['BirthYear'][i] -= timedelta(days=365.25*100)
    i = i+1
    if i==250:
        break
```