# I want to convert (01-07-57) to date value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image]

I want to convert the datum column which is a string to `DateTime` format.

when I use

```
sf['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(sf['Datum']).dt.date
```

its showing the year as 2057 instead of 1957

Comment: How did you get that data in the first place? It looks like SMHI historical temperature data, and their CSV downloads usually have sane dates (i.e, four-digit years). Also, you have somehow got the header lines at the start of the file imported as a column. I recommend some upstream data clean-up...

Answer (score 0):

There's a answer over here:
[pandas to_datetime parsing wrong year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766353/pandas-to-datetime-parsing-wrong-year)

It's due to 2 digit years from 0-68 mapping to 20xx.

Answer (score 0):

what if just replace years?

```
sf['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(sf['Datum'].str.replace(r'(\d\d)$',r'19\1'))
```