# Pandas string to datetime not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Apologies if this is somewhere else, I did a search and wasn't able to find anything. I'm working on a Udacity nanodegree, a project where you investigate a dataset. I'm trying to clean the data by changing a `release_date` column from a string to a datetime. This is all being done in Jupyter with Pandas if that matters at all.

Before changing the datatype, I did a `df['release_date'].tail()` and got this:

```
10861     6/15/66
10862    12/21/66
10863      1/1/66
10864     11/2/66
10865    11/15/66
Name: release_date, dtype: object
```

I converted the data type with `df['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['release_date'])`
and it worked, but some dates are adding 100 years. Now if I do a `df['release_date'].tail()`, the dates come back like this:

```
10861   2066-06-15
10862   2066-12-21
10863   2066-01-01
10864   2066-11-02
10865   2066-11-15
Name: release_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Any date after 1/1/1973 converts properly, but anything prior to that date adds 100 years

Is this a formatting thing that I'm not aware of with Pandas or Jupyter, something else I need to give it to only change the datatype?

The csv file this is being read from has the date in a format like '6/20/1966' for every year in the column if that matters for anything as well.

Comment: i don't think you have rows that contain wrong data in your examples

Comment: [Python and short years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766353/pandas-to-datetime-parsing-wrong-year)

Comment: Thanks markalex, looks like my searching skills need help

Comment: Lesson; ***always*** use ISO8601

Comment: Try that:
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m/%d/%y',yearfirst=False).dt.strftime('19%y-%m-%d')    <<<
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])